# event 'hide' on last items of list

Tags: jquery, events, html-lists, show-hide

I'm trying to do a pagination for Bing API 2.0 To show the pagination numbers I have set this code:

```
 if (webResultTotal > 100)
        {

            $('.numbers:lt('+(100)+')').show();
}
```

This means that if the results are more than 100, then 100 pagination numbers (with Class numbers) have to show. Normally they have display:none;

So my problem is if the results are less than 100. I tried solving this by:

```
if (webResultTotal < 100)
        {

            $('.numbers:lt('+Math.min(webResultTotal)+')').hide();

        }
```

This will hide the numbers which look like this:

```
<li class="numbers"><a href="#"> 1 </a></li>
<li class="numbers"><a href="#"> 2 </a></li>
<li class="numbers"><a href="#"> 3 </a></li> etc..
```

The problem is that it will hide BEGINNING FROM THE FIRST of the list instead of hiding the last numbers. So it will not show 1,2,3 Instead it will hide themm and show the last of the li items. How do I change the code in order to hide in a negative way, so hide the li items from the end ---> begin instead of the other way around?

Please note that I stripped my code to make the question simple, my real code looks different.

Comment: It looks like `$('.numbers:lt('+webResultTotal+')').show()` should work in all cases -- no `if`s, no buts. What the deal?

Comment: @Jon Suppose they would all have to show, all 100 of them. Now suppose only 10 have to show and the others have to hide....Thats wy the IF's (You have quit a reputation, strange you have to ask this...but maybe I misunderstood you)

Comment: The question is simply hard to understand, rep has nothing to do with it. How many `li class="numbers"` are there in the page? Always 100? If not always, how many?

Comment: @Jon There are 900 which on load have css display:none; (Why should it matter how much there are..?)

Comment: @Jon Suppose the numbers go from 1 to 10. Then my code will preserve 7 items. So what it does is hide 1 to 3, I want it to hide 8 to 10 and show 1 to 3.

Comment: I hope you are not being serious with "why should it matter?". If what you have in your page doesn't matter then what does matter? Anyway, I believe this is enough information to answer the question (see below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a "very large" number of `.numbers` elements in your page, and you want to show/hide the appropriate number based on the number of returned results, a good solution would be:

```
var itemsToShow = Math.min(webResultTotal, 100);
$("li.numbers").slice(0, itemsToShow).show().end().slice(itemsToShow).hide();
```

However, the concept of having prepopulated the page with lots of elements might not be the best approach vs generating elements as required on the fly; unfortunately this is something that cannot be tackled without more information.

Comment: Thanks:) I still have to test this but I think its a good answer. Im working with the Bing API 2.0 which is sometimes not that logical. I tried dynamic pagination in the past, it doesnt really work. The results sometimes change on them selves. So I would get results and I would see them change right in front of me! So experimented and found out that putting the pagination physically in the html  solves this problem.